# Metric Spaces Admitting Injective Contraction

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

It's clear that every $X$ is a Banach space then the map $x \mapsto .5 x$ is an injection from $X$ to itself which is contractive.  In general if $X$ is a metric space, does there necessarily exist an injective contractive map from $X$ to itself.

Comment: Try to construct such a map for $X=S^1$ and see what happens.

Comment: If $X$ contains exactly two points there is clearly no such map.